# How to call two 'on click' events

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a list of districts as well as corresponding Taluks. When I click on a district, it will display a district report in a JQX pie chart. But when I click on Taluks, it will display district reports and sometimes Taluk reports. Currently, I am using this on click events[image: onclick events].

```
$(function () {

    $("#menuwrapper ul>li").click(function () {

        var districtname = this.id;
        GetDistrictReport(districtname);
        showresults(districtname);
        //alert('Clicked list. ' + a);
    }); 
});
$(function () {

    $("#menuwrapper ul>li>ul>li").click(function () {
        //var districtname = this.id;
        var talukname = this.id;
        GetTalukReport(talukname);
        showTalukresults(talukname);
        //alert('Clicked list. ' + a);
    });

});
```

That menu wrapper `id` stems from

```
<div class="ui-layout-east" style="background-color: #bccbde">

            <div>
                <div style="width: 25%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000">

                    <ul id="menuwrapper" style="position: absolute; top:-10px; left:-40px;">

                        <%--<li>--%>
                        <%--<a href="#">Districts</a>--%>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="Bagalkot"><a href="#">Bagalkot</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="Badami"><a href="#">Badami</a></li>
                                    <li id="Bagalkot"><a href="#">Bagalkot</a></li>
                                    <li id="Bilgi"><a href="#">Bilgi</a></li>
                                    <li id="Hungund"><a href="#">Hungund</a></li>
                                    <li id="Jamkhandi"><a href="#">Jamkhandi</a></li>
                                    <li id="Mudhol"><a href="#">Mudhol</a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li id="Bangalore"><a href="#">Bangalore</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="Anekal"><a href="#">Anekal</a></li>
                                    <li id="Bangalore East"><a href="#">Bangalore East</a></li>
                                    <li id="Bangalore North"><a href="#">Bangalore North</a></li>
                                    <li id="Bangalore South"><a href="#">Bangalore South</a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>

                            <li id="Bangalore Rural"><a href="#">Bangalore Rural</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="Devanahalli"><a href="#">Devanahalli</a></li>
                                    <li id="Dod Ballapur"><a href="#">Dod Ballapur</a></li>
                                    <li id="Hosakote"><a href="#">Hosakote</a></li>
                                    <li id="Nelamangala"><a href="#">Nelamangala</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li id="Belgaum"><a href="#">Belgaum</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="Athni"><a href="#">Athni</a></li>
                                    <li id="Belgaum"><a href="#">Belgaum</a></li>
                                    <li id="Chikodi"><a href="#">Chikodi</a></li>
                                    <li id="Gokak"><a href="#">Gokak</a></li>
                                    <li id="Hukeri"><a href="#">Hukeri</a></li>
                                    <li id="Khanapur"><a href="#">Khanapur</a></li>
                                    <li id="Parasgad"><a href="#">Parasgad</a></li>
                                    <li id="Ramdurg"><a href="#">Ramdurg</a></li>
                                    <li id="Raybag"><a href="#">Raybag</a></li>
                                    <li id="Sampgaon"><a href="#">Sampgaon</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because events propagate from child to parent. It would work fine when you would click on District's li, but would show weird behavior when you would click on Taluk's li (because Taluk's li is the child of District's li and the event propagates from Taluk's li to District's li and triggers it).

You should therefore use event.stopPropagation();

```
$("#menuwrapper").find("ul>li>ul>li").click(function (event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation === "function") { event.stopPropagation(); }
    var talukname = this.id;
    GetTalukReport(talukname);
    showTalukresults(talukname);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.but after using the above stopPropagation(); code it will display same no change at all. when I click on taluk it will display both district and taluk.